# What can I do when I create an event listener for a button and it tells me it doesn't exist?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am working in eclipse making a temperature converter app. I made a `JButton btnConvert`. However, when I go to make the event listener it tells me `btnConvert cannot be resolved.`

I noticed it isn't showing up where the other controls are listed on the outline either and I clearly have it in my code:

```
JButton btnConvert = new JButton("Convert");
```

Can anyone help? I have everything imported that needs to be imported and didn't run into any issues until this.

Comment: Also, could you post your full class code, so we can have context

Comment: This website provides free expert help; so anybody asking a question here can reasonably be expected to put in the required effort. And since you want free help from us, why would we care whether you are getting paid? Even though it might not seem like it, this website is actually more friendly towards low-effort newbie posts than it used to be (but only because we're forced to be)

Comment: @Chris G I don't have anything in this post about getting paid. That was another post that I had deleted.

Comment: ....yeah, you deleted it, so I posted here because I wasn't sure whether you got the message. Never mind though.

Comment: @Chris G, yeah I got the message, I just went ahead and deleted that post until I had more time to read the posting rules more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button was only created in a method, then it will only be visible within the scope of that method, and if you're trying to access it outside of the method it was created in, it will say it can't find the button. Instead, you may want to use an instance variable, it would look something like this:

```
public class WhateverYourClassNameIs 
{
    public JButton btnConvert; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //define the instance variable, this doesn't have to be in main
        // it can be wherever you are initializing the code you're working on
        btnConvert = new JButton("Convert"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, that is the issue, there needs to be a instance variable.